# How to configure/calibrate our new UGEE 1910 monitor and pen

Tags: graphics-tablet

We have connected all up, display works fine....but...the pen show a cursor about 4 cm to the right

downloaded a few drivers, uninstalled each time before installing new, no change

whats the most common settings for the front button and back button of the pen

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a windows device, open up the tool tray in the bottom right of your screen and click the icon that shows a tablet and pen. Then, navigate to the calibration tab, check the calibration box, and select '9-point calibration'. Then, simply use the pen to click the pink dots.

Hope this helps!